# Cannot send keys to screensaver in windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, screensaver

How can I send keys to a screensaver in Windows 10. I have tried to install my own screensaver and have disabled logon screen so I only need a keypress to show my desktop. I Guess a part of the problem is use of different desktop, but even With the code shown in the link bellow I cannot figure out how to send a key Message to the screensaver. Any suggestions?

http://www.delphipraxis.net/1059352-post7.html

Comment: For security reasons you won't be able to do this. Why would you need to fake input to a screensaver anyway?

Comment: To disable screensaver, since the program I want to run is dependent on mouse click on the screen, and I have not figured out any other way.

Comment: That makes no sense to me at all

Comment: If the application wants a mouse click then the screensaver will be disabled when the mouse is moved to do that click. Or are you simulating mouse behaviour?

Comment: Well, first a keypress or mouse click to disable screensaver, and then I can proceed With other programs and sending mouseclick to them.

Comment: Have a look at SendInput along with setting SPI_SETBLOCKSENDINPUTRESETS via SystemParametersInfo. It seems from some posts that it might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  You are asking how to send keys to a screensaver to deactivate it, so it does not interfere with simulated mouse clicks you want to send to another app.  That is the wrong question to ask.  You should be asking how to disable the screensaver from running in the first place while your app is busy interacting with the other app.

You say you have disabled the screensaver password.  In which case, you can have your app handle the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx) message. If the message's `wParam` value has the `SC_SCREENSAVE` flag enabled, discard the message without passing it to the default message handler.  Then the screensaver will not run.  This only works if your app is in the foreground at the time (`SC_SCREENSAVE` is only sent to the foreground window), and only if the screensaver password is disabled, though:

> If password protection is enabled by policy, the screen saver is started **regardless of what an application does with the SC_SCREENSAVE notification**—even if fails to pass it to DefWindowProc.

If you need to handle the message while your app is not in the foreground, you can use a global message hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) to change `WM_SYSCOMMAND`/`SC_SCREENSAVE` messages into `WM_NULL` when being sent to any `HWND` in the system.

An alternative approach (only if the screensaver is not already running) is to use [`SystemParametersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) to set `SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE` to TRUE to make the system *think* that a screensaver is already running so it wont start another one (you can use `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING` to check if one is running).  This is an *old-school* way to avoid a screensaver from starting, however on Vista+ onwards with added security policies and such, this probably does not work as well as it once did.

Another alternative is to disable the screensaver in the Registry while your app is busy*.  Set the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Desktop\ScreenSaveActive` value to `0` (just make sure to restore it before your app exits).

<sub>*This technique is even used by Windows itself (Vista+) if the user dismisses the screensaver immediately after it starts.  Windows assumes the user is annoyed with the screensaver, so the screensaver gets disabled, and is then re-enabled a few minutes later.</sub>

Comment: About your last point; He must also take note that if his application has an abnormal termination (the app crashes or is "End tasked") then that registry setting will remain.

Comment: Yes, and even Windows sometimes forgets to restore the setting after disabling it, thus leaving the screensaver permanently disabled. It is not a perfect system, but it is what is available.

Comment: Don't you use SetThreadExecutionState to keep the display on?

Comment: Since my program does not follow a spesific time shedule I would prefer that the screensaver is disabled when necessary. But I understand there is no simple solution. I thought it would be easy to Direct keypresses or mouse event to the screen saver desktop, but apperently it is not.

Comment: @victor: the options I have presented allow you to disable the screensaver on an as-needed basis.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the `SetThreadExecutionState()` documentation says: "*This function does not stop the screen saver from executing.*".

Comment: @Remy OK, thanks. So it just keeps the screen on, even if it shows a screensaver. Seems like a weak design to me.

Comment: Change of registry setting as suggested above does not disable a running screensaver on my pc.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to automatically exit the screen saver once it is running. The only option is to prevent it from starting, and even that has become much more difficult since Windows Vista.

Comment: To exit a screensaver that is already running, you can simply "jiggle" the mouse with `SendInput()`, the screensaver won't know the difference between it and the user physically moving the mouse. But, if the screensaver security policy is enabled then the user will get prompted for a password before returning control to the desktop.

Comment: Jiggle the mouse does not work on Windows 10 on my system.

Comment: @victor: I was not aware of `SPI_(GET|SET)BLOCKSENDINPUTRESETS` when I wrote that comment. From the documentation: "*a BOOL indicating whether an application can reset the screensaver's timer by calling the SendInput function to simulate keyboard or mouse input... **TRUE if the screensaver will not be deactivated by simulated input**, or FALSE if the screensaver will be deactivated by simulated input.*" So you will have to set that value to FALSE before jiggling the mouse in code.

Answer (score 1):

I had given up on this but i stumbled over the following code that Works

```
 function KillScreenSaverFunc(Handle: hwnd; Temp: LongInt): Boolean; stdcall;
 begin
   PostMessage(Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
   KillScreenSaverFunc := TRUE;
 end;

procedure KillScreenSaver;
var
  myHDESK:hdesk;
begin
   myhdesk := OpenDesktop(Pchar('Screen-saver'), 0, FALSE,      
   DESKTOP_READOBJECTS or DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS);
   if myhdesk<>0 then begin
    EnumDesktopWindows(myhdesk, @KillScreenSaverFunc, 0);
          CloseDesktop(myhdesk);
 end;
end;
```